# Add DividerItemDecoration both sides of recyclerView

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I'm trying make **GUI** for an app in Android I'm novice in that.

First I make a horizontal `recyclerView`, add `DividerItemDecoration` with a custom drawable and and setup `LinearSnapHelper` for always snap to center.

It works, but the left side is next to side of the screen because `dividerItemDecorator` only put the line between elements.

[image]

Exists any way to put divider at start of the `recycler`, I have tried put some padding or margin but when I slide it "cuts" before reach the end of the screen

Sorry in advance for the English

**My code is**

**MainActivity**

```
@BindView(R.id.rvRecentNews)
RecyclerView rvRecentNews;
private ArrayList<String> horizontalList;
private HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

horizontalList=new ArrayList<>();
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 1");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 2");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 3");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 4");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 5");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 6");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 7");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 8");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 9");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 10");

    horizontalAdapter=new HorizontalAdapter(horizontalList);

    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    rvRecentNews.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(rvRecentNews.getContext(),
            horizontalLayoutManagaer.getOrientation());
    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_divider));

    rvRecentNews.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(rvRecentNews);

    rvRecentNews.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.sgd.pawfriends.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/rvRecentNews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="salir"
    android:onClick="logout"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to create custom `ItemDecoration`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
```

`clipToPadding="false"` means, only clip when scroll reaches to end/start point.

Comment: it works but only the first element, the others and the res elements not apply the change. thanks for the help

Comment: @SebastianDaza did you remove dividerItemDecorator? You need to use both padding and dividerItemDecorator together. I said it before, clipToPadding works for only start/end points.

Comment: i try both option, remove dividerItemDecorator and with it, but the problem is  with add android:clipToPadding and dividerItemDecorator is when i add LinearSnapHelper because inner element snap to center but because the padding only affect the first and last element the other not snap correctly

Comment: @SebastianDaza it looks like your item width is the problem, if it is match_parent, change it an give fixed and smaller value than screen width.

Comment: i found a solution in this page [https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/a-view-divided-adding-dividers-to-your-recyclerview-with-itemdecoration/], i create a custom divider in this case but android:clipToPadding work me in other case thanks for your help @OğuzhanDöngül

Answer (score 0):

I found in this page many options for implement custom ItemDecoration

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/a-view-divided-adding-dividers-to-your-recyclerview-with-itemdecoration/

and i only change

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(rvRecentNews.getContext(),
            horizontalLayoutManagaer.getOrientation());

    dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.line_divider));

    rvRecentNews.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

for this

```
rvRecentNews.addItemDecoration(new StartOffsetItemDecoration(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.line_divider)));
```

class StartOffsetItemDecoration

```
public class StartOffsetItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int mOffsetPx;
private Drawable mOffsetDrawable;
private int mOrientation;


public StartOffsetItemDecoration(int offsetPx) {
    mOffsetPx = offsetPx;
}

public StartOffsetItemDecoration(Drawable offsetDrawable) {
    mOffsetDrawable = offsetDrawable;
}


@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);


    mOrientation = ((LinearLayoutManager) parent.getLayoutManager()).getOrientation();
    if (mOrientation == LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) {
        if (mOffsetPx > 0) {
            outRect.left = mOffsetPx;
            outRect.right = mOffsetPx;
        } else if (mOffsetDrawable != null) {
            outRect.left = mOffsetDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            outRect.right = mOffsetDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        }
    } else if (mOrientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        if (mOffsetPx > 0) {
            outRect.top = mOffsetPx;
        } else if (mOffsetDrawable != null) {
            outRect.top = mOffsetDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
    if (mOffsetDrawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mOrientation == LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL) {
        drawOffsetHorizontal(c, parent);
    } else if (mOrientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        drawOffsetVertical(c, parent);
    }
}


private void drawOffsetHorizontal(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent) {
    int parentTop = parent.getPaddingTop();
    int parentBottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();
    int parentLeft = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int offsetDrawableRight = parentLeft + mOffsetDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

    mOffsetDrawable.setBounds(parentLeft, parentTop, offsetDrawableRight, parentBottom);
    mOffsetDrawable.draw(canvas);
}

private void drawOffsetVertical(Canvas canvas, RecyclerView parent) {
    int parentLeft = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int parentRight = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();
    int parentTop = parent.getPaddingTop();
    int offsetDrawableBottom = parentTop + mOffsetDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

    mOffsetDrawable.setBounds(parentLeft, parentTop, parentRight, offsetDrawableBottom);
    mOffsetDrawable.draw(canvas);
}
```

Thanks to author of the post David Greenhalgh and Shayan Pourvatan for the idea to create custom class